# Get OpenBook markets for token mint

Tags: serum

Is there a way to find every existing OpenBook market given a token mint address on-chain, so without using the Raydium API or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a better method but  one way to sniff these kind of things out:

first find a test market address, find its base and quote token mints, and then:

```
        const tokens = [
        baseTokenMintString,
        quoteTokenMintString]

        const market = await connection.getAccountInfo(yourTestMarketAddress)
        let x = 0
        let y = 32
        while (y <= market.data.length) {
        let sliced = new PublicKey(market.data.subarray(x, y)).toString()        
        if (tokens.includes(sliced)) console.log(sliced, x, y) }
        x++
        y++
```

and using the x and/or y as offsets plus the mint youre searching for:

```
const accounts = await connection.getProgramAccounts(openbookProgram, {filters: [{dataSize: 388}, {memcmp: {offset: x, bytes: searchMint}]})
```