How to get OpenBook Market ID of a token using web3js?
I have a token mint address (CA) and I want to find its OpenBook Market ID using web3js (and or @openbook-dex/openbook). I couldn't find any information on this so if you could give me some hints, I would be thankful.
Thanks.

https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/8407/get-openbook-markets-for-token-mint
this is the only source I could find. I would also like to know if there is a more convenieny way to get market from mint address
